# Lucene docFreq returning 0

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene 3.1 to index some documents.

When I use IndexSearcher.search(), I successfully get back results for queries.

**However, when I use IndexSearcher.doqFreq(), I get back 0 for a term**. Can anyone offer some insight?

Also, why is there both an IndexSearcher.docFreq() and IndexReader.docFreq()? I have tried both, and both give me 0.

Here is my code:

```
    IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(dir);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

    ...

    String seachTermString = "foobar";
    String field = "body";
    Term term = new Term(field, searchTermString);
    int numDocs = searcher.docFreq(term);
```

and then I get numDocs=0, even though when I use IndexSearcher.search() with the same search term string, I get back hits.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting your term completely to lower case letters.

Comment: Can't believe this helped me in 2022

Answer (score 1):

Create TermQuery from the Term you are creating to get document frequency with search.docFreq(term). Use this TermQuery for searching and check if it yields any results. It should. If this TermQuery doesn't give any results, something is amiss in the query creation in the step 1 of search in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding your Fields with the Field.TermVector.YES option enabled?

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("value", documentContents, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TermEnum`:

```
Term term = new Term(field, searchTermString);
TermEnum enum = indexReader.terms(term);
int numDocs = enum.docFreq();
```

And you don't need the `IndexSearcher`